# IIS 7 + Url Rewrite: files don't show up on subdomain

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I use URL Rewrite on IIS 7.5 and I created a rule to rewrite subdomains like this "test.localwebsite.com" -> "test.localwebsite.com/test" and then I do additional rewrite with this URL and content on the page loads just fine, but files won't load, they have such URL "test.localwebsite.com/design/style.css". How to make them load?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Subdomain Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(?:www\.)?(?:([^.]+)\.)?localwebsite\.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must ignore rewrite fro css, axd files and images that also will make errors in empedded resources.

```
.*?$(?<!\.css)
```

OR

```
.*?$(?<!\.css|.axd)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot that I accept all urls with (.*) pattern. Updated my rule to match all except specific file extensions: <match url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js)(\?.+)?)$" ignoreCase="true" />

Comment: goodluck, my advice to handle your images that typed incorrectly - without extension - to add an extension automatically, because these wrong images will cause another request to your asp.net handler.